# Change border size of the "hasControls" in fabricJs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I would like to further customize the look and feel of the fabricJs `hasControls` border size. It currently is drawn on the canvas with a 1px border but a 3px border is what I am trying to accomplish.

the fabricJS docs do not have any custom properties to change this border size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fabricjs objects with `hasControls` property set to true also have a `borderScaleFactor` and a `borderColor` properties.

```js
color.addEventListener('change', function(){
    canvas.getActiveObject().borderColor = this.value;
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
scale.addEventListener('change', function(){
    canvas.getActiveObject().borderScaleFactor = this.value;
    canvas.renderAll();
  });


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png', function(img) {
  img.scale(0.4).set({
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    angle: -15
  });
  img.borderColor = color.value;
  canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js"></script>
<input id="color" type="color" value="#FF00FF"/>
<input id="scale" type="range" max="2" min=".01" step=".01"/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```